# Meteor Collections that expire after an amount of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, meteor

I'm thinking that should be done in a Collection, It's important that the data is cleared after a certain amount of time though.

Is it possible to set an expiration date for a Meteor Collection?

I want to clear the collection after 30 seconds after my post request.

```
 Meteor.methods({
test_brief : function (test_id) {
    check(test_id, String)
    if (!test.findOne({_id: test_id})) {
      test.insert({
          _id: test_id, 
          creationDate: new Date(),
          expireAfterSeconds: 30,

        }
    )
```

Comment: You have to use Meteor.setTimeout function to clear collection or if the data can stay in collection, the i would use Meteor.publish function to publish only for 30secs.

Comment: @iiro it's a POST request i want to add the collection only for 30secs after that i need to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an index in your collection like the following

```
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        test.rawCollection().createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30, background: true } );
    }
```

and your Meteor.methods should be something like this

```
    Meteor.methods({
        test_brief: function (test_id) {
            check(test_id, String);

            if (!test.findOne( {_id: test_id} )) {
                test.insert(
                    {
                        _id: test_id,
                        'createdAt': new Date(),
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

Have a look at this, it might help you
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/